# I cannot use the Color.FromName(string s) method

Tags: c#, colors

I need to use the FromName Method, but for some reason it is not available.
I have been googling for a while but I cannot find a solution.

[image]

Comment: What framework version are you targeting? If you hover over `Color` does it show the full name of `System.Drawing.Color`? (I'm wondering whether there's another `Color` structure in scope...)

Comment: If i hover over Color it says: struct System.Windows.Media.Color

Comment: Okay, well that's the problem. It would have helped if you'd shown all the using directives... Do you need anything from `System.Windows.Media`?

Comment: I need this to change the background of a label.

Comment: Please add WPF tag.

Comment: @wetallday: So do you need a `System.Windows.Media.Color` or a `System.Drawing.Color` for that?

Comment: Teacher says we need the System.Windows.media to change the background of the label.

Comment: @Berkay What is a WPF tag?

Comment: Right, if you need `System.Windows.Media.Color` then you don't want to use `System.Drawing.Color` anyway. As for the wpf tag - it's a tag on the question. You've currently got the c# and colors tags - add the wpf tag.

Answer (score 2):

I thinks you also have a reference to [System.Windows.Media](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media(v=vs.110).aspx), hence the IDE is trying to refer to its [Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color(v=vs.110).aspx) class methods.

Try `var c = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("colorname");`

Comment: Why would it be using `Colors` when the code has `Color` (singular)?

Comment: According to MSDN it is `public sealed class Colors`

Comment: @S.Dav: They're two different types: [Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.Drawing.Color.FromName instead of Color.FromName. If that doesn't help, maybe the problem comes from the Framework, which is quite unlikely ..

Comment: It is telling me "The type or namespace name 'Color' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing'(are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Maybe you can try one of the solutions below but they are pretty similar to this one, so I don't know how to help, sorry